# Plaing Voice using Xna Framework

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xna, kinect

I am taking audio from kinect device and sending those byte array to client and client receive those byte and play using xna  DynamicSoundEffectInstance class ,but the problem i am facing is that client receives some bytes and the program automatically terminates without any Exception
server Code

```
KinectSensor kinectsenser;
    Thread obj;
    TcpClient client;
    TcpListener server;
    NetworkStream ns;
    Stream kinectaudio;
    soundcontainer.SoundData sound =null;
    Thread obj1 = null;
    Object objt = new Object();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 45000);
        server.Start();
        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        ns = client.GetStream();
        sound = new SoundData();
        obj1 = new Thread(send);


    }
    void audio()
    {
        byte[] soundSampleBuffer = new byte[1000];
        kinectaudio = kinectsenser.AudioSource.Start();

        obj1.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            lock (objt)
            {
                int count = kinectaudio.Read(soundSampleBuffer, 0, soundSampleBuffer.Length);
                sound.data = soundSampleBuffer;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (KinectSensor.KinectSensors.Count == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("no Kinect Device is attched");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
        kinectsenser = KinectSensor.KinectSensors[0];
        kinectsenser.Start();
        audio();
    }
    void send()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            lock (objt)
            {
                soundcontainer.SoundData i = new SoundData();
                i.data = sound.data;
                if (i.data != null)
                {
                    if (ns.CanWrite)
                    {
                        ns.Write(i.data, 0, i.data.Length);
                        ns.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Client Code is as follows:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream ns;
    Thread iiui;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPAddress ip=IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        client.Connect(ip, 45000);
        ns = client.GetStream();
        iiui = new Thread(start);
        iiui.Start();
    }
    void start()
    {
        DynamicSoundEffectInstance sound = new DynamicSoundEffectInstance(16000, AudioChannels.Mono);
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
        sound.Play();

        IFormatter formater = new BinaryFormatter();
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] temp = new byte[65536];
            ns.Read(temp, 0, temp.Length);
            sound.SubmitBuffer(temp, 0, temp.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a note, I ran across this issue as well, and the problem is that you are overflowing the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` with buffers.  When you call `SubmitBuffer()` you are adding the byte buffer to the end of it's internal buffer, and when it crashes, it is because the buffer is overflowing.
Try this:

```
while (sound.PendingBufferCount > 3) { Thread.Sleep(1); }
sound.SubmitBuffer(temp, 0, temp.Length);
```

This should fix any problems you are having.
What this does is it waits for the `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` to have only 3 buffers in it's internal buffer to prevent overflowing.  It's also a good idea to make the buffers smaller to prevent lag (if you care about it).

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be helpful, but have you considered your network to be the issue? Does your firewall unblock port 45,000?

In addition to that you should consider using the port ranges: 49152–65535 instead, as those are used for private and dynamic ports not registered with IANA.

EDIT: 
Also, the IP address you are using is your loopback address. Is this intentional? Otherwise the traffic virtually goes nowhere.

Comment: I'd assume the address is because he is testing by running the client and server on his machine.

Comment: @Cyral I thought that at first too, but typically the Kinect sensors is connected to an Xbox and not a computer. If the sensor was connected to his machine then networking them seem rather unorthodox.

Comment: i have also tried by change the port number but it doesn't works jhon